# Given a Hilbert space separable prove exists $\{u_j \}_{j \in N}$ indipendent so that $\overline{span}\{u_j\}_{j\in N}$=H

Tags: real-analysis

Using induction we may discard each $u_{j}$ which is a linear combination of the previous vectors in the sequence in order to arrive at a new sequence $\{ t_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of vectors for which the $\{ t_{1},t_{2},\cdots,t_{k}\}$ is linearly independent?

Comment: You'll need to assume $H$ is infinite-dimensional too; finite dimensional inner product spaces are all separable Hilbert Spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** You need a little more than just an  infinite sequence $\ \left\{t_n\right\}_{n=1}^\infty\ $ of vectors such that $\ \left\{t_n\right\}_{n=1}^k\ $ are linearly independent for every $\ k\ $, since the space $\ \{v\}^\perp\ $, where $\ v\in\cal{H}\ $ is non-zero, will contain such a sequence with $\ v\not\in\overline{\text{span}}\left\{t_n\right\}_{n=1}^\infty\ $.

The key is to start off with a sequence $\ \left\{t_n\right\}_{n=1}^\infty\ $ *which is dense in $\ \cal{H}\ $*.  Such a sequence *must*  exist, because $\ \cal{H}\ $ is separable.  *Then* your procedure of discarding any $\ t_j\ $ which is a linear combination of the preceding ones will give you the sequence you want.

Comment: I don't understand how create the sequence

Comment: Do you mean the starting sequence?  You don't need to create it.  Since you're told the Hilbert space is separable, then, *by the definition* of separability, you *know* that such a sequence must exist, so you simply declare that you will use the symbols "$t_n$" to refer to the terms of one such.

Answer (score 0):

Every separable Hilbert space $H$ has  an orthonormal basis $(u_n)$ which is an infinite sequence if the space is infinite dimensional. Also, $u_i$'s are necessarily independent and their span is always dense in $H$.